# Использование структур и указателей

Tags: c++, структуры

Начал изучать `С++`. Есть код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct student
{
    string name;
    int year;
    int course;
};

int main()
{
    student st1;
    cout << "Имя студента: ";
    cin >> st1.name;
    cout << "Год рождения: ";
    cin >> st1.year;
    cout << "Курс: ";
    cin >> st1.course;
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("111.dat", "wb");
    fwrite(&st1, sizeof(student), 1, f);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Тут всё понятно. Добавляем:

```
student st2;
FILE *f2;
f2 = fopen("111.dat", "rb+");
fread(&st2, sizeof(student), 1, f2);
fclose(f2);
cout << "Студент " << st2.name << ", " << st2.year << " года рождения учится на " << st2.course << " курсе.";
```

и получаем ошибку "*** Error in `/home/artik/Документы/QTProjects/build-untitled-Desktop-Release/untitled': free(): invalid pointer: 0xbfe10d44 **" (ОС - Ubuntu). Хотя после текста ошибки выводится верный результат. А вот код

```
student *st2 = new student();
FILE *f2;
f2 = fopen("111.dat", "rb+");
fread(st2, sizeof(student), 1, f2);
fclose(f2);
cout << "Студент " << st2->name << ", " << st2->year << " года рождения учится на " << st2->course << " курсе.";
```

ошибки не вызывает. Хотя оба варианта, по идее, должны работать. Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваша программа имеет неопределенное поведение.

Вы не можете хранить таким образом объект типа `std::string`, а затем восстанавливать его. Вам следует написать отдельную функцию сохранения структуры, которая вместо объекта типа `std::string` будет сохранять строку, возвращаемую методом `c_str` класса `std::string`.

То, что программа работает иногда, может быть связано с тем, что строки малой длины, обычно меньше 16 байтов, объект типа `std::string` хранит внутри себя, не выделяя для строк отдельно память.

Еще одно различие между структурой в первом вашем примере, когда она выделяется в стеке, и структурой, которая выделяется динамически, связано с тем, что для структуры, выделенной в стеке, компилятор сам вызывает деструктор, и, соответственно, вызывается деструктор члена данных с именем `name` структуры.

Это сообщение об ошибке

> "*** Error in
>   `/home/artik/Документы/QTProjects/build-untitled-Desktop-Release/untitled':
>   free(): invalid pointer: 0xbfe10d44 **"

как раз, скорей всего, и связано с тем, что был вызван деструктор для структуры.

А для структуры, созданной вами самим в динамической области памяти, вы деструктор не вызываете. Поэтому данный член данных не освобождается.

Чтобы было более ясно, в чем заключается проблема, то класс `std::string` можно условно представить себе следующим образом

```
class string
{
private:
    char *ptr;
    //...
public:
    //...
};
```

когда вы присваиваете объекту типа `std::string` значение, или инициализируете объект, то класс выделяет память для строки

Таким образом, например, объявление

```
std::string s( "Hello, World!" );
```

приводит к тому, что объект `s` в общем случае динамически выделяет память для хранения данного строкового литерала

```
ptr = new char[n];
```

где `n` - это длина строкового литерала. Этот адрес является корректным, пока работает программа.

Если вы записали объект в файл, а затем считали его из файла при новом запуске программы, то значение в указатели `ptr` будет уже не корректным, так как программа в данном сеансе не выделяла память по этому адресу.

Comment: Понял из Вашего ответа, что причина в типе данных string. Заменил на char[] и всё заработало. Но всё равно сути не понял. Не могли бы разжевать новичку? Или может на примере?

Comment: @Artik Объекты std::string внутри себя содержат указатели на выделенную для строки память. При записи этих указателей в файл, а затем при чтения из файла в новый объект структуры, эти указатели в общем случае становятся не корректными.

Comment: Т.е. тип string - это указатель и в файл я записываю указатель на строку?

Comment: @Artik Фактически, так.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Потихоньку приходит понимание.

Comment: @Artik Не за то.:)

Comment: Интересно то, что в Windows такая ошибка не появляется. Только что попробовал.

Comment: @Artik Это зависит от того, как вы запускали программу. Если вы записали структуру в файл, а затем сразу же считали, то ничего не произойдет.

Comment: И на компутере под Ubuntu, и на компе под Windows я запускал один и тот же скомпилированный текст программы (записываю структуру в файл и следом его же считываю). Ubuntu ошибку выдаёт, Win нет. Сижу вот на работе и пытаюсь во всём разобраться. Как пишут на форумах, такая ошибка выскакивает при попытке очистить область памяти, уже очищенную ранее. Сижу, курю стеки и кучи.